# Nesting 2 csv files in d3.js

Tags: csv, d3.js

**Newbie Question:** I've recently started using D3 and have been playing with examples etc. Have been having some success using .nest on a single csv file but would like to be able to do the equiv. of an SQL Join - ie. load one csv file with Country level data and then nest with children data in a second file.

Parent level Country Data (csv file excerpt) - plus any other country level data...

```
Country,ID,Status,...[other Country fields]...
Afghanistan,AF,CAND
Albania,AL,CAND
Australia,AU,OTHER
Azerbaijan,AZ,COMP
Burkina Faso,BF,CAND
Cameroon,CM,CAND
Central African Republic,CF,COMP
Côte d'Ivoire,CI,CAND
Democratic Republic of Congo,CZ,CAND
```

Then build in "Reports" as Child level Data (csv file excerpt) against each Country

```
Country,CountryReport,YearsCovered,SectorsCovered,...[other Report fields]...
Afghanistan,http://eiti.org/report/afghanistan/2008,2008,"Mining"
Afghanistan,http://eiti.org/report/afghanistan/2009,2009,"Mining"
Albania,http://eiti.org/report/albania/2009,2009,"Oil, Mining"
Azerbaijan,http://eiti.org/report/azerbaijan/2007,2007,"Oil, Gas"
Azerbaijan,http://eiti.org/report/azerbaijan/2008,2008,"Oil, Gas"
Azerbaijan,http://eiti.org/report/azerbaijan/2009,2009,"Oil, Gas, Mining"
Azerbaijan,http://eiti.org/report/azerbaijan/2010,2010,"Oil, Gas, Mining"
Azerbaijan,http://eiti.org/report/azerbaijan/2011,2011,"Oil, Gas, Mining"
Burkina Faso,http://eiti.org/report/burkina-faso/2008,2008,"Mining"
Burkina Faso,http://eiti.org/report/burkina-faso/2009,2009,"Mining"
Burkina Faso,http://eiti.org/report/burkina-faso/2010,2010,"Mining"
Cameroon,http://eiti.org/report/cameroon/2004,2004,"Oil, Gas"
Cameroon,http://eiti.org/report/cameroon/2005,2005,"Oil, Gas"
Cameroon,http://eiti.org/report/cameroon/2006,2006,"Oil, Gas, Mining"
Cameroon,http://eiti.org/report/cameroon/2007,2007,"Oil, Gas, Mining"
Cameroon,http://eiti.org/report/cameroon/2008,2008,"Oil, Gas, Mining"
```

Any ideas how best to address this? I've tried using the .nest but I think that implies that the parent level data needs to be included in each row of the child file?

If I could load the csv data into global variables I could build this structure - but d3js does not appear to allow this. An explanation of this would also be appreciated

The example code at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests

```
var data; // a global

d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(json) {
  data = json;
  visualizeit();
});
```

...does not appear to work for csv data - or maybe I'm not getting something?

Comment: csv data can be parsed using d3.csv()